# Rails on development mode without Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, puma

After I have installed Puma for production mode, it should not run on my local machine, however Puma is starting on development mode and stops after a moment with no errors.

```
$ rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[8707] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[8707] * Version 3.1.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: El Niño Winter Wonderland
[8707] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 6
[8707] * Environment: development
[8707] * Process workers: 1
[8707] * Phased restart available
[8707] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[8707] Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

It looks like is a bundler issue: 
[github.com/puma/puma/issues/983](http://github.com/puma/puma/issues/983)

Comment: try to disable puma gem in your gemfile `#gem 'puma', '~> 3.4'` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks  mrvncaragay! It's work only if I remove puma from the production, but I do need puma in the production mode

Comment: easy fix. uncomment in porudction mode. comment in development mode :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a real solution but a nice work around for people that using there server for production mode with Puma and want to work on local machine development mode with WEBrick. This solution base on mrvncaragay idea

1.
split you `Gemfile` to 3 files:

```
Gemfile_base
Gemfile_development
Gemfile_production
```

in Gemfile_base include all the `gem`s that not test, development & production. There is not reason to include `source 'https://rubygems.org'` or in Gemfile_development or Gemfile_production file.
in Gemfile_development include only test & development `gem`s
in Gemfile_production include only production `gem`s

2.
Replace all the line in the `Gemfile` to:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemfiles = [ 'Gemfile_base', 'Gemfile_development' ]
#gemfiles = [ 'Gemfile_base', 'Gemfile_production' ]
gemfiles.each do |gemfile|
  instance_eval File.read(gemfile)
end
```

3.
Deploy to production server

4.
Add Gemfile to .gitignore file

```
#bundle Puma in development mode bad wordaround
Gemfile
```

5.
Untrack Gemfile from source control

```
git rm --cached Gemfile
```

6.
Change the commit line in of Gemfile in production server from:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemfiles = [ 'Gemfile_base', 'Gemfile_development' ]
#gemfiles = [ 'Gemfile_base', 'Gemfile_production' ]
gemfiles.each do |gemfile|
  instance_eval File.read(gemfile)
end
```

to:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#gemfiles = [ 'Gemfile_base', 'Gemfile_development' ]
gemfiles = [ 'Gemfile_base', 'Gemfile_production' ]
gemfiles.each do |gemfile|
  instance_eval File.read(gemfile)
end
```

Comment: Why would you do this rather than use bundler' group feature?

Comment: @FrederickCheung because `group` is not working at all with `puma` in production mode ([Check this](http://github.com/puma/puma/issues/983)). In any case, this is not a solution I could implement in my system, is trying to reinvent the wheel in some way. I'll keep using puma in dev until a better option (or a bug fix) arrives.